# Should I use SmartGWT or Vaadin?

Tags: performance, gwt, web-applications, smartgwt, vaadin

I'm going to develop a web application using SmartGWT. I've heard about Vaadin framework. I wonder what is the best to use? 
My application will be used by **~500 users at the same time**. And I need **high response performance** and **high security control**. I won't need dozen of pretty widget just enough to be able to use pretty tabbed pane and table. So what is the best choice regarding my needs?

**Edit :**
I'll also need a tool to export table content to Excel format (like in Google Doc SpreadSheet).

ps : already check this one [Should I use Vaadin Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183801/should-i-use-vaadin-framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into both these frameworks, and others, and decided to go with the core GWT widgets.  You desire to have high response performance will be difficult with Vaadin since it sends almost everything back to the server.  And if you don't need super fancy widgets then the core widgets (plus some incubator/3rd party ones as needed) should be fine.  I didn't get deep into testing SmartGWT, but it seemed to really tie you into their framework (making it difficult to use core widgets as well) and I read about difficulties when starting to do things different than the showcase examples.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've chosen SmartGWT eventually, mainly because he proposed a tool to generate excel form and I need that stuff!

Comment: It's common that people choose a framework for a widget they particularly need, I don't think it's really an excellent manner of doing even If I did the same thing for Smartgwt with it's TreeGrid...

Answer (score 4):

If you write your Vaadin application properly, it will be performing perfectly well (check this one: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Optimizing%20Sluggish%20UI).

If you know SmartGWT, use it. Also, if you have no experience with Vaadin, use SmartGWT. It might take you a lot of time to learn Vaadin (it requires some practice after one is able to create well performing application). The biggest problem of Vaadin that it is very easy to write slow application - because everything seems to be so easy and one tends to use many components and so on...

Comment: I've never use Vaadin so I will choose SmartGWT for this project. Maybe an other time I hope, seems to be a nice framework ;) Ty for answer!